# I can't get my plot to knit to PDF without getting an error message

Tags: r, plot

For some reason I keep getting an error that cancels everything when I try to knit. It keeps telling me that the error is in the line with plot() and I don't know what to do. It's having trouble finding my dataset but I don't know how to fix it.

```
Plot(movement_data$Dose,movement_data$Move,xlab="Dose",ylab="Move",main="Embryo movment vs dose of CBD")
library(gplots)
plotmeans(Move~Dose,data=movement_data,mean.labels=TRUE,connect=FALSE)
```

Comment: Please include the _exact_ error in your question

Comment: You can create a code block for the code and make the question easier to read by adding 4 spaces before each line.

Comment: Why is`Plot` capitalized?